# New to unity and c#, unexpected symbol issue in (14,29)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

in my code theres this error 
Assets/TextChangeScript.cs(14,29): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `(', expecting`,', `;', or`='

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class TextChangeScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text m_MyText;
    public Text OtherText;

    void Start()
    {
        m_MyText.text = "There was once a mother and her child";
        yield WaitForSeconds (3);
        m_MyText.text = "The mother loved her child very dearly";
    }
}
```

Comment: `yield new WaitForSeconds(3)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to call `yield WaitForSeconds` in a function that doesn't return an `IEnumerator`. You need to create a new function that returns `IEnumerator` and call it with `StartCoroutine`.

The code after the `yield` will be executed.

You can check the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html). Unity is well documented.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class WaitForSecondsExample : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Text m_MyText;
    public Text OtherText;


    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Example());
    }

    IEnumerator Example()
    {
        m_MyText.text = "There was once a mother and her child";
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
        m_MyText.text = "The mother loved her child very dearly";
    }
}
```

Comment: While your answer fixes his problem, maybe consider adding a short description of what was the error, and how your solution fixes it.

Comment: The code after yield return will be executed because the return type is IEnumerator, this has nothing to do with coroutines, this is normal c# behaviour. You can even add multiple yield returns in a single method

Comment: @Eddge my post was edited, now my code shows its original anwser

Comment: @Chopi I removed my mark down, and posted an edit to remove the inaccurate comment made by hector. (In regards to a yield return)

Comment: @mohammed if it's the solution to your problem upvote and mark the question as solved please.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Coroutine](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html), Unity is well documented on how they work and you can use the link in Chopi's answer.

Now to avoid any confusion, normally in a function you will want a return to be the last call in your function as code behind it typically does not get called.  This is not the case for an IEnumerator.

The line `yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);`  returns an expression from a function and is used as a place to mark where execution is to continue, in this case in 3 seconds at that line.

Your start method is not an IEnumerator, and as far as I am tracking there isn't a way to yield in your start in Unity.  You can start a coroutine in start and have that coroutine yield.  Here is an example of a coroutine that will give you, your 3 second delay between your text:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class TextChangeScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text m_MyText;
    public Text OtherText;

    IEnumerator StoryText() {
        m_MyText.text = "There was once a mother and her child";
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (3);
        m_MyText.text = "The mother loved her child very dearly";
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (3);
        m_MyText.text = "Then one day blah blah blah";
    }

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(StoryText());
    }

    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

Here is an example of using a for loop to loop through text with a 3 second delay between them:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class TextChangeScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text m_MyText;
    public List<string> storyText;

    IEnumerator StoryText() {
        foreach (string sz in storyText)
        {
            text.text = sz;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(3); // in 3 seconds. execution will begin here and iterate to the next string in the storyText.  
        }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(StoryText());
    }

    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

Edit:

Thanks to what R1PFake shared in the comments you can also do this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CenterName : MonoBehaviour {
    public Text text;
    public List<string> storyText;

    // Use this for initialization
    IEnumerator Start () {
        foreach (string sz in storyText)
        {
            text.text = sz;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need the coroutine in this case, because you can use IEnumerator as a return type instead of void for the Start method, it's a little "hidden" feature.